# Expression type 'NSLayoutConstraint' is ambiguous without more context

Tags: ios, swift, paging

I'm receiving the following error when I try to make a build of my iOS app. How can I find out what is causing it?

> Error: Expression type 'NSLayoutConstraint' is ambiguous without more context

Code:

```
private func centerIndicator() {
    let xCenterConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(
        item: loadingView ?? default value, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal,
      toItem: indicator, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0
    )
    loadingView.addConstraint(xCenterConstraint)

    let yCenterConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(
      item: loadingView, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal,
      toItem: indicator, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0
    )
    loadingView.addConstraint(yCenterConstraint)
  }
```

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce this. Can you provide a [mcve]?

Answer (score 1):

Your most likely culprit is `default value`, it shouldn't be there. If `loadingView` is non-optional you can just delete `?? default value`. If it *is* optional, then you should probably be wrapping this in an `if let loadingView = loadingView` block. Setting constraints on random views will not work out.

Next, Apple doesn't suggest adding constraints to views directly anymore. Instead, use the `isActive` property.

```swift
NSLayoutConstraint(
      item: loadingView, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal,
      toItem: indicator, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0
).isActive = true
```

But these are pretty simple constraints. An even better way is to use layout anchors instead.

```swift
loadingView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: indicator.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
```